# Implement NavigationDrawer icon like in android L

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

How to Implement `NavigationDrawer` icon like in `Android L`.

I have updated play store app where i can see icon of navigation drawer something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=h4M5WOqL8_4):

Here  big change is the new “`hamburger`” button, which is bigger, spaced off from the left edge, and no longer has a category icon. Clicking on it opens up the side menu, and the icons turns into a back arrow with a smooth little animation.

Is it possible to implement the same in lower versions of android ?

Any example or sample ?

Comment: This lib can interest you: https://github.com/markushi/android-ui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Edit - October 18th

As of October 17th it's not necessary to use a Third-Party library for this anymore. Google just released the Android 5.0 SDK along with a new `v7 appcompat library`. The new v7 appcompat *[added support for material design user interfaces](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)* and **updated ActionBarDrawerToggle, which contains the menu-to-arrow animation**.
So in order to have the Burger-to-Arrow animation in your NavigationDrawer you just have to use the new ActionBarDrawerToggle (import `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`) and the NavigationDrawer like before (see [Developer Training](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)).

---

While the ***[ActionView by markushi](https://github.com/markushi/android-ui)*** gives you the desired transformation between the burger-icon and the arrow it lacks the option for being used in the "Standard" ActionBar. For this you should consider to use the library ***[material-menu by balysv](https://github.com/balysv/material-menu)***.

The usage of the library itself may be straightforward, but if you've used the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` previously you should remove it.

Following just a little "How to" for everyone who wants to use the `DrawerLayout` without the ActionBarDrawerToggle but with the `MaterialMenu` library:

#### 1 - Add library in build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    //...
    compile 'com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu:1.3.1'
}
```

#### 2 - Init *MaterialMenuIcon*

```
materialMenu = new MaterialMenuIcon(this, Color.WHITE, MaterialMenuDrawable.Stroke.THIN);
```

#### 3 - Set DrawerListener and change *IconState* accordingly

```
   mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            materialMenu.setTransformationOffset(
                    MaterialMenuDrawable.AnimationState.BURGER_ARROW,
                    isDrawerOpened ? 2 - slideOffset : slideOffset
            );
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            isDrawerOpened = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            isDrawerOpened = false;
        }
    });
```

**Note:** `isDrawerOpened` should be global variable

#### 4 - Open/Close NavDrawer

Add this to `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

```
   if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    }
```

**Note:** Since we're not using the ActionBarDrawerToggle we have do this on our own.

Further steps like saving the state of the MenuIcon can be found [here](https://github.com/balysv/material-menu#use-as-action-bar-icon-stock-compat-or-sherlock).

### Edit

As mentioned by [Piyush Kukadiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2651081/piyush-kukadiya) MaterialMenu uses `NineOldAndroids` for compatibility reasons. If you don't want this because your app only supports API-Level 11 and above here's what you roughly need to do (though I'd say it’s probably not worth the hassle - furthermore you'll only save 39kb):

1. Download the Library from GitHub
2. Import it as a new module to your Project
3. Set it as a dependency to your app-module
4. Remove compile `'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'` from `build.gradle` file of the library and set `minSdk` to 11
5. Remove any import referecing `com.nineoldandroids.*`

Comment: Initially got some errors like `ResourceNotFoundexception` but i solved it. It's working thank you.

Comment: This library also includes `NineOldAndroids` . Is it possible without
`NineOldAndroids` ? because my target version is `HoneyComb` means no need of `NineOldAndroids` hence can reduce application size.

Comment: This is possible yep, please see me edit. Though I gotta say it's not worth it, you'll only save 39kb.

Answer (score 0):

As Google release the new support library [Android Support Library, revision 21](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html),you can see how to achieve the effect in [ActionBarDrawerToggle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) this page.